# If a newborn was born Oct 31 st then how would you know how many months their turning if some of the months don't go up to 31 days?

Tags: infant

Give me information and why you chose what you said as your answer please .

Comment: most parents just pick the 3th or the first (o2 28/29 when counting February).. not that big a deal :| unless you got insane parents who say stuff like "My child just turned 1503 days old!"

Comment: If you want to be precise then you should use seconds....

Comment: @Solar: the question then just becomes how many seconds is a month?

Comment: @dxh no, the question becomes how many seconds have elapsed since the birth - easy with a timer...

Comment: There are 12 months in a year. It doesn't really matter if they have 28, 29, 30, or 31 days, does it? We say a month. My daily meds are prescribed a month at a time; the prescription states "30 tablets", which makes me short by a day every other month or so. I don't really care. In medicine, as in life, a month is roughly 30 days. If a doctor tells a patient on February 1st that they have 3 months to live on, the patient usually doesn't ask, is that 89, 90, 91, or 92 days? Is that counting today?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to know how many months they're old? If it's just for inconsequential monthly celebrations, then when exactly you celebrate would also be inconsequential. If your doctor is asking, then they most likely don't expect a 100% perfect answer, or they would ask for the date of birth instead. If it's for another reason, it's probably going to depend on the context.

Comment: This isn't a parenting question.

Comment: It depends if that 31st October was on a leap year or not...

Answer (score 10):

"Months" of age is an approximate concept at best, so its going to depend on the context. SE.Law has a discussion of the [relevant bit of English law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/542/the-legal-length-of-one-month) for contracts that specify a term of months, which is that:

> if the period expired on a date that did not exist in a particular month (eg 31st February), then the period would expire on the last day of that month.

So in the UK a child born on 31st October would be legally one month old on the 30th November.